# Getting values stored in some specific indices in an array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a String array and let us suppose that I want to get the third , 7th and 11th members from the array and apply some function to these arrays.

I know that I can do it the java way like using if statement but I want to do it the scala way

As an addition to the question, let us suppose that original string has multiple words seperated by comma. I want to apply some mentioned to the third, 7th and 11th members, while rest of the string remains the same.

In other words if the input string was

i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11

I want to change it to

i1, i2, f(i3), i4, i5, i6, f(i7), i8, i9, i10, f(i11)

Currently, I am doing it this way

```
def process(lin1:String):String=
    {

            val line:Array[String]=lin1.split(";")
            var iLength=line.length
            var iTotalColumns=28
            var i=0
            var output:String=""
            for( i<-0 to iLength-1){


                var sTemp=line(i)
                if((i==3)||(i==7)||(i==11))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def selective(f: String => String, ixs: Seq[Int])(in: String) =
  in.split(";").zipWithIndex
    .map { 
      case (str, ix) if (ixs.contains(ix)) => f(str)
      case other => other._1
    }
```

Example call:

```
scala> val input = "entry1;entry2;entry3;entry4;entry5;entry6;entry7;entry8;entry9;entry10;entry11"
input: String = entry1;entry2;entry3;entry4;entry5;entry6;entry7;entry8;entry9;entry10;entry11

scala> selective(_.toUpperCase, List(2,6,10))(input)
res3: Array[String] = Array(entry1, entry2, ENTRY3, entry4, entry5, entry6, ENTRY7, entry8, entry9, entry10, ENTRY11)
```

Comment: How can I make the selective function return the modified string. I am confused as the map with in the selective function is working on splitted string

Comment: Are you asking how to get the resulting Array[String] back as a single String? If so, just use `mkString` on the result (eg. `...map{...}.mkString(";")`).

Comment: The problem is that I can do mkString but cannot get this value at the point of call. Sorry, I am at beginner level in Scala. I am invoking it like this \n scala.io.Source.fromFile(inputPath+fileName).getLines() map(l=>selective(func,List(1,2,3,26))(l))

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you want `selective` to return a `String` instead of an `Array[String]`, tack `.mkString(";")` on the end of the map within `selective`. If you want to do it in the map over the lines as per your latest comment, tack it onto the end of the function call: `...(l).mkString(";"))`. If neither of those cases match your problem, maybe break it out into a separate question?

Comment: Basically I just want to print the line after scala.io.Source.fromFile(inputPath+fileName).getLines() map(l=>selective(func,List(1,2,3,26))(l))

Comment: @Shadowlands, it is better to use `Set` since you're using the collection only to test elements presence. `Set` is more performant for this (though it probably does not matter much when the collection is small).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Actually, presuming we are talking about the parameter I labelled `ixs`, I'd be inclined to go further and define it as a function from Int => Boolean to be more general.

Comment: @Shadowlands, yeah, you're absolutely right. `Set` is `Int => Boolean` after all)

Comment: @Raza, are you using the modified lines other than to dump them to output? Try calling mkString in the ways I have suggested above, and assign the output to a variable to work with further, or dump to output as you see fit.